# Trying to change format of list in python

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, substring

I have something like

```
[['b c', 'd e', 'f'], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['b c', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'g', 'f']]
```

but I am trying to change this to

```
['(b c) d e f', 'b c d e f', '(b c) d b e g f']
```

I have tried several different things but the parenthesis are messing up my approach. I was able to join the strings without the parenthesis. Is there any easy way to do this in python?

Comment: What is the logic that determines when the parentheses should appear and when they should not? I'm especially confused about why `d e` isn't parenthesized in the first list.

Comment: in the first sublist it is unclear why `(b c)` is in parens, but not `d e`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
new_list = [" ".join(words if not " " in words else "({})".format(words) for words in seq)  for seq in original_list]
```

But assuming the logic for parentheses is that they are added whenever there is one space in the string being joined.  But that implies your example is incorrect.  If the parentheres should be added only to the first string in each sub-list, then you have to include counting in the conditional:

```
new_list = [" ".join(words if not " " in words and i == 0 else "({})".format(words) for i, words in enumerate(seq))  for seq in original_list]
```